# positioned three blocks in the table-cell

Tags: html, css

How to position three blocks in the `table-cell` follows: `p1` top, `p2` bottom, `p3` in the middle?

The html as next:

```
  <div id="table">
    <div id="row">
        <div id="r2"></div> 
        <div id="r3"></div>
        <div id="r1">
            <div id="p1">top</div>
            <div id="p3">middle</div>
            <div id="p2">bottom</div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

CSS

```
    #table{
        display: table;
        width:500px;
        height:500px;
        max-height:500px;
        min-height: 500px;
    }
    #row{
        display:table-row;
    }

#r1, #r2, #r3{
 display:table-cell;
 }
```

Details - http://jsfiddle.net/2ZF6J/

Comment: What is not working with your current approach?

Comment: Your fiddle works for me. But why are you emulating a table, by the way?

Comment: I change the layout under ie7.
How to position three blocks in the <div id="r1"> follows: p1 top, p2 bottom , p3 in the middle.
Help please.

Comment: Unless you really need to use IE7, I highly recommend that you upgrade to a newer browser. It has less than 0.5% market share these days.

Comment: I know that. But this is task. So can you help me?

Comment: Do you mean you want each of p1,p2,p3 to be 1/3 the height of r1?

Comment: .p3 must be in center cell.
.p2 must be in the footer of cell.
and .p1 must be in top of cell.
Idea must work in IE7.

Comment: See my solution below. Hope it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE7 does not support `display: table` so you can just simply use floats and absolute positioning.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="r2"></div>
  <div id="r3"></div>
  <div id="r1">
    <div id="p1">top</div>
    <div id="p3">middle</div>
    <div id="p2">bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
  width:500px;
  height: 1px;
  min-height: 300px;
}

#r1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 177px;
  border:1px solid black;
}

#r3 {
  width: 156px;
  background-color: #aef;
}

#r2 {
  width: 161px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color: #eee;
}

#r1, #r2, #r3 {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

#p1, #p2, #p3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#p1 { 
  top: 0;
  background-color: gold; 
}

#p2 { 
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: crimson; 
}

#p3 { 
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  background-color: orange; 
}
```

See it here: http://jsbin.com/ekImIYih/3